# Combine 4 integer bytes to a 32bit unsigned int in android studio

Tags: android, stm32

I want to send a 32bit timestamp from my stm32wb55 to my own android app.
This is how I split the timestamp in 4 bytes on the microcontroller and send these over BLE to my phone:

```
void calculate_timestamp(void){

//splitting in 4 bytes
uint8_t time_micro32_1 = time_micro32 & 0xFF;
uint8_t time_micro32_2 = (time_micro32 >> 8) & 0xFF;
uint8_t time_micro32_3 = (time_micro32 >> 16) & 0xFF;
uint8_t time_micro32_4 = (time_micro32 >> 24) & 0xFF;

//send the bytes over ble
P2P_Server_App_Context.Acceleration.Timestamp_1 = time_micro32_1; //8
P2P_Server_App_Context.Acceleration.Timestamp_2 = time_micro32_2; //9
P2P_Server_App_Context.Acceleration.Timestamp_3 = time_micro32_3; //10
P2P_Server_App_Context.Acceleration.Timestamp_4 = time_micro32_4; //11
```

}

"time_micro32" includes the time in microseconds since startup from the microcontroller and will be displayed correct on my putty-console!
And this is how I combine the 4 bytes in android studio:

```
//NotificationValue[8] includes value of time_micro32_1
//NotificationValue[9] includes value of time_micro32_2
//NotificationValue[10] includes value of time_micro32_3
//NotificationValue[11] includes value of time_micro32_4

int Timestamp = (NotificationValue[8] << 24) | (NotificationValue[9] << 16) | (NotificationValue[10] << 8) | (NotificationValue[11]);
```

I display the timestamp in my activity like this:

```
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.Time_TextView)).setText("Timestamp = "+ Timestamp );
```

But the values in my activity never makes sense. The values are false and be often negativ (what is never desired by timestamps).

I think, I combine the bytes in android studio not the right way. But I have no more idea how can I do this. I tried many, but nothing was successfull.

Does anyone have an idea how can I combine the bytes in android correctly? Or have I made a mistake by splitting the timestamp on my microcontroller? In the end, I want to display the timestamp in microseconds on my activity as a 32bit unsigned integer.

Thankfull about every help...

---

EDIT: At the end, I have noticed that I have interchanged my MSB and LSB in my timestamp, too. This would be the right order:

```
    int Timestamp = (NotificationValue[11] << 24) | (NotificationValue[10] << 16) | (NotificationValue[9] << 8) | (NotificationValue[8]);
```

Comment: `time_micro32` You are not defining nor assigning domething to that variable. Do it! And tell us in hexadecimal notation the value of those four bytes. On the receiving side you should also display those values hexadecimal as it is the quickest way to see if you got the four bytes.

Comment: `//send the bytes over ble` ?? That does not send anything as far as i can see. What are you doing instead?

Comment: `"time_micro32" includes the time in microseconds` If it is indeed an integer then put a known value in it and look at the other side if you got it back.

Comment: int time_micro32 = 0x18E49B8C; or something like that. Then you immediately know that at receiving side you should get the bytes 0x8C, 0x9B, 0xE4 and 0x18. And the sequence may vary.

Comment: `(NotificationValue[8] << 24)` You did not say that you would do something with endianess. So i expected you to write `(NotificationValue[8] << 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**unsigned integer**

```
byte[] NotificationValue = new byte[] { (byte)0xFC, (byte)0xFD, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0xFF };
long Timestamp =
      ((NotificationValue[0] & 0xFFL) << 24) //00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_11111111_00000000_00000000_00000000
    | ((NotificationValue[1] & 0xFFL) << 16) //00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_11111111_00000000_00000000
    | ((NotificationValue[2] & 0xFFL) <<   8) //00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_11111111_00000000
    |  (NotificationValue[3] & 0xFFL); //00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_11111111
```

**signed integer**

```
byte[] NotificationValue = new byte[] { (byte)0xFC, (byte)0xFD, (byte)0xFE, (byte)0xFF };
int Timestamp =
       (NotificationValue[0] << 24) //11111111_00000000_00000000_00000000
    | ((NotificationValue[1] & 0xFF) << 16) //00000000_11111111_00000000_00000000
    | ((NotificationValue[2] & 0xFF) <<  8)  //00000000_00000000_11111111_00000000
    |  (NotificationValue[3] & 0xFF);       //00000000_00000000_00000000_11111111
```

Comment: thank you so much! In addition, I have interchanged my MSB and LSB in my timestamp. I have corrected it in my post. With that fix and with your contribution now it works

Comment: You can just reverse them to get `unsigned integer (little endian)` like so: `long Timestamp = (NotificationValue[0] & 0xFFL) | ((NotificationValue[1] & 0xFFL) << 8) | ((NotificationValue[2] & 0xFFL) << 16) | ((NotificationValue[3] & 0xFFL) << 24));`

Answer (score 1):

it's not a one liner but you can try this to get the bytes re-assembled.

```
    unsigned int timestamp = NotificationValue[8];

timestamp = (timestamp<<8)+NotificationValue[9];
timestamp = (timestamp<<8)+NotificationValue[10];
timestamp= (timestamp<<8)+NotificationValue[11];
```

for some reason i feel that the bit shifts you were doing was mangling the data.

edit:

didn't know java doesn't use unsigned types. You could use  a long instead, and convert it to unsigned.

```
long timestamp = NotificationValue[8];

timestamp= (timestamp<<8) + NotificationValue[9];
timestamp= (timestamp<<8)+ NotificationValue[10];
timestamp = (timestamp<<8)+ NotificationValue[11];

timestamp = timestamp & 0xffffffffL; //this should remove the signage
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not working. Same problem like before, and "unsigned int" is not allowed in android studio.

Comment: For respecting your contribution, I have tried your solution in my code, too. At first look, it seems to be correct. But it isn´t always. Can not tell you why unfortunately. Thanks anyway!